# Border color for part of the bottom of li

Tags: html, css

I have the next list: http://jsfiddle.net/4Mc7X/190/

```
ul {
    padding: 0;

}
li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    width: 114px;
    border: solid 1px #f00;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Is there an option to make the red border not all the bottom?

for example:

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not if you set the bottom-border on the `li`.

Your best option is to use another styling element within the `li`, like a `div`. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GYatesIII/kXTBE/).

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Stuff
        <div></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    border: solid 1px red;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
div {
    width: 60%;
    border-bottom: solid 1px red;
}
```

---

Here's a [different solution](http://jsfiddle.net/GYatesIII/kXTBE/1/), using the `:after` pseudo class as suggested by @Sean Dunwoody.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Stuff
    </li>
    <li>
        More Stuff
    </li>
    <li>
        Even More Stuff
    </li>    
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    border: solid 1px red;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

li:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px red;
    width: 80%;
}
```

NOTE: `:after` is not supported in IE7-.

Comment: you should accompany your fiddle with the appropriate code, fiddles don't last forever.

Comment: +1 for the `:after` example included - I would have had it positioned but your way is actually better (didn't realise it worked that way but it makes a lot of sense thinking about it). Don't think the `height: 1px` is necessary though.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a border on the div and give it a percentage width so that it isn't 100% the width of the li, like so:

```
li {
    border: solid 1px #f00;
    border-bottom: 0;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 114px;
}

div { border-bottom: 1px solid #f00; width: 80%; }
```

(obviously you also need to remove the bottom border of the li for this to work)

And a fiddle if you want to see it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/C2ttY/

Comment: Keep in mind, if you wrap your content in the div, then the content will only stretch 80% of the `li` as well.

Comment: I think it can be overcome with clever use of overflows and height (although that feels a bit hacky to me), you could probably also accomplish it with `:after` in some way. Hopefully that isn't a requirement, guess we'll see what the OP says.

Comment: `:after` Is also a good idea. I included a solution using that in my answer.

Comment: I do love `:after`, it means we can avoid a lot of HTML that's only there for presentational purposes. The only downside I see is IE7 lacks support for it - hopefully IE7 support isn't a requirement here though.

Comment: Thankfully, I don't support IE7 as a default anymore. Either analytics have to show it has heavy use on that site or a client has to request it. I'm already looking forward to the day I can say the same thing about IE8!

Comment: Same with me really, feeling exactly the same way about IE8 (and 9 to a lesser degree)!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with the :after pseudo element, without putting an extra div inside your li:

```
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
</ul>

ul {padding:0;}
li {float:left; padding:0; width:114px; border:solid 1px #f00; border-bottom:none; margin:0; position:relative;}
li:after {content:""; border-bottom:1px solid #f00; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; width:100px; height:0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Mc7X/191/

Answer (score 0):

why not have a background image on the li to create that bottom border effect.
1px high red and fairly wide - like 300px - save as an png-8 or gif to keep file size down. Then align to the bottom of the li and 10px from the right with:

```
li {
float: left;
padding: 0;
width: 114px;
border-top: solid 1px #f00;
border-left: solid 1px #f00;
border-right: solid 1px #f00;
margin: 0;
background-position: right 10px bottom;
background-image: url("yourborderimage.png");
display: block;
padding: 4px 0 4px 0;
}
```

Comment: Extra background image = extra page request, hence slowing down the load time of the page (albeit by a very small amount, maybe worth it for mobile though). It also means you don't have flexibility if the `li` is wider that you're expecting it to be.